# Automatic height of css grid elements in flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, overflow, css-grid

I want the program to consist of one main component. Various card lists are to be rendered dynamically in this main component. The main component should be 100vh high. The individual cardlists should take up the space available. If there is not enough space, the grid of a cardlist should be scrollable.

For this I use flex-box for the main component. every single item that is in the main component receives the css class flex: 1. this should allow all items to use the space available.

The problem is, however, that the individual items use more than 100vh in total, as no overflow is activated ...

If I comment out in the class cardList flex: 1 and instead set a static height of 100px, overflow is activated. It should be possible to solve this problem with flex: 1, but I have the feeling that I am missing something.

A link to the codepen is down below.

Note: If I activate flex: 1 for .grid and delete all items, each cardList takes the correct amount of height.

Comment: Link to the codepen: https://codepen.io/m-michalek/pen/rNaGEvP

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using css nth elements to select individual boxes or a group of them

kind of hard to get what the problem is?

https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-of-type/

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp

eg

```
p:nth-child(odd) {
  background: red;
}

p:nth-child(even) {
  background: red;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment.

My goal is to render different card lists. a cardList consists of a heading and a css grid which contains different cards. My backend decides how many of the cardLists have to be rendered. No matter how many cardLists are to be displayed, no more than 100vh should be exceeded. 

What I tried is that the individual card lists are arranged by flexbox, so that the available space is used dynamically. If there is not enough space, the grid should overflow.

Unfortunately that does not work. the cardLists take up more than 100vh.

Comment: so your saying the max height for the ".main-component" class is the height of the window browser and the ".cardList" class should fit inside and if the height of the card list is too long then scroll right?

Comment: what is the max amount of card list class you are able to render or is it infinity

Comment: so what div classes do u want to be able to scroll? sorry kinda confused still